# UIImagePickerController not always Fullscreen (strange Statusbar behavior)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar, uistatusbar

i need a UIImagePickerCOntroller, so that the User can take some photos. This is my Code:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    UIImagePickerController * imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.showsCameraControls = YES;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;


    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

For the first time i open the UIImagePickerController everything works fine! But for the Second, third... time i always get this:

[image]

As you can see the Camera Controls above gets cut. It looks like the StatusBar is the Problem. I tried everything like:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

or

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

But nothing worked. Maybe an Apple Bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- Go to Info.Plist
- Set Status bar is initially hidden YES
- Set View controller-based status bar appearance NO

Comment: @Davis still you found the status bar ?

Comment: There is no statusbar when i open the UIImagePickerController, but still the black area like in the screenhot above...maybe the statusbar isn´t the problem..

Comment: May be you haven't removed status bar from xib

Comment: In my xib the statusBar is set to "None", this should be right i hope^^

Comment: Try this last :
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}

Answer (score 0):

Implement `- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden` in your view controller and return `YES` or `NO` based on the current conditions. When you want to hide/show, call `- (void)setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` on your view controller.